# Is it possible to 'superimpose/show' non-heatmap related data over an Excel range heatmap?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, heatmap

Is it possible to 'superimpose/show' data from a similarly shaped matrix over a range heatmap, instead of simply showing/hiding the underlying heatmap data?

The question could also be rephrased differently: Is it possible to generate a heatmap on any given range (say `A1:C3`) based on a data range elsewhere on the sheet (e.g. `F1:H3`)? If yes, one could make visible the `A1:C3` values over the heatmap.

The goal here is simply to get the heatmap to show more information and following (very basic) screenshot will clarify what I am looking for:

[image: Regular heatmap & custom one showing data from a different range]

The left one is an actual standard one built from the data behind the coloured background, while the one I am looking for (in the middle) is built using the same data than the left one for the heatmap itslef, but showing/superimposing a set of values from the range at its right (this was done using a picture paste).

Once again, the idea is to convey 2 times more information: one set through colour, and another one, different, using data from another range.

Obviously useful when the two data sets are related in some way.

Comment: To your question, `Is it possible to generate a heatmap on any given range (say "A1:C3") based on a data range elsewhere on the sheet (e.g. "F1:H3")` the answer is yes. However, I don't know what you mean by, `If yes, one could make visible the "A1:C3" values over the heatmap.` Can you clarify what you mean by this? Can you  create an example layout of what you want the output to look like? If you can provide such an example (i.e. a screenshot of Excel with the layout you desire), I should be able to provide you a solution.

Comment: Hi Brian... Thx for your reply; just added some clarifications.

Comment: I see exactly what you want to do and initially I thought it was possible using Conditional Formatting. I thought that creating a rule using formulas would work but it won't. I am going to post an alternative that works but is more work that it really should be. I am also playing around with VBA to see if something easier can't be accomplished; however, I am a novice so don't hold your breath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I could think of at this time is to use Excel's Linked Picture utility. Here is how it works (based on your example - adapt as needed):

1. Insert 4 columns right of column `C`
2. In cells `E1:G3` link them with a formula to cells `A1:C3` (e.g. in `E1` write formula `=A1` and so forth

[image]

3. In cells `E1:G3` apply the same conditional formatting as in cells `A1:A3`. (unless you have another purpose, you really don't need conditional formatting for `A1:C3`)

[image]

4. In cells `E1:G3` format cells with custom type `;;;` (note: conditional formatting is missing in `E3:G3` in picture below because I took screenshots out of order)

[image]

5. This is what your worksheet should look like at this point

[image]

6. Select and copy cells `M1:O3`, go to cell `E1` and paste special `Linked Picture`.

[image]

That's It.

Now you can alter values in cells `A1:C3` to change the conditional formatting in `E1:G3` and you can alter value in cells `M1:O3` to change values in `E1:G3`. If `E1:G3` is the output you want to see, you can move `A1:C3` and `M1:O3` somewhere else - they are now simply used for inputs. I did not use the cells in `I1:K3` in your example because they weren't needed (and obviously you used them just as an example. I wish this could be done more elegantly but this seems to be it given Microsoft Excel limitations. What you are asking would be a great feature I can see being useful.

Comment: Many thanks Brian, a rather creative solution using a feature (linked picture) I never thought existed and even less so used:-)  Even in the case of a highly dynamic Excel table environment, this should do the trick nicely.  Many thanks again for the little trick (and the very detailed procedure:-)...

Comment: My pleasure. Please mark it as an answer when you have a moment.